# control-middlemouse no longer brings up xterm menu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xterm

For as long as I've used `xterm`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>MiddleMouse</kbd> has brought up a menu with important items like resetting the scroll buffer.

For some reason <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>MiddleMouse</kbd> no longer brings up any menu for me. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>LeftMouse</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>RightMouse</kbd> bring up menus, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>MiddleMouse</kbd> doesn't do anything.

For completeness sake, I am using `i3wm` on Linux v6.0.5, `xterm` 375-1, but I haven't changed anything in `.Xresources`, `.Xmodmap` or `.i3/config` in a long time.

Additionally, when I run `xterm` under the old school `twm` window manager, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>LeftMouse</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>MiddleMouse</kbd> bring up the same `xterm` menu. Something's changed with `xterm`.

Comment: Which operating system and which version of xterm are you running? Could the hotkey combinations be intercepted by some other program so that they no longer reach xterm?

Comment: @sudodus - I'm running Linux, v6.0.5, xterm 375-1. I don't think there's a hotkey combo involved, as I get xterm menus from ctrl-LeftMouse and ctrl-MiddleMouse. I've also tried running xterm 375-1 under the "twm" window manager 1.0.12-1, where ctrl-MiddleMouse brings up the same menu as ctrl-LeftMouse.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. I must admit, that I don't know why this is happening. My versions of xterm are older (version 372 or older), and are not affected. Maybe the best way to continue is to file a bug against xterm.